# How to set the same height of paragraphs present in different divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

This is my HTML code.

```html
<div id="all_projects">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="proj col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-9">
      <div id="img" class="hvr-curl-top-left">
        <img src="{% static 'car_game.jpg' %}" alt="car_game_image">
      </div>
      
      <div id="proj_data">
        <h5 style="font-weight:bold;">Overdose Racing</h5>
        <p>This is a simple 2d game created with python using PyGame framework.All the game assets created with InkScape</p>
        <a href="https://github.com/Maninder-cell/Car-Race-Game" target="_blank">
          <xmp>
            </get the code>
          </xmp>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="proj col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-9">
      <div id="img" class="hvr-curl-top-left">
        <img style="background-color:lightsteelblue;" src="{% static 'crossandzero.png' %}" alt="cross and zero">
      </div>
      
      <div id="proj_data">
        <h5 style="font-weight:bold;">Tic Tac Toe</h5>
        <p>This is a simple 2d game created with python using PyGame framework.All the game assets created with InkScape</p>
        <a href="https://github.com/Maninder-cell/cross-and-zero" target="_blank">
          <xmp>
            </get the code>
          </xmp>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="proj col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-9">
      <div id="img" class="hvr-curl-top-left">
        <img src="{% static 'eminem.png' %}" alt="Eminem">
      </div>
      
      <div id="proj_data">
        <h5 style="font-weight:bold;">Eminem Music</h5>
        <p>This is a simple website created with html, css and javascipt.The Songs are present on Google Drive.</p>
        <a href="https://maninder-cell.github.io/Music-site-Eminem-/main.html" target="_blank">View Website</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="proj col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-9">
      <div id="img" class="hvr-curl-top-left">
        <img src="{% static 'image10.png' %}" alt="QnA site image">
      </div>
      
      <div id="proj_data">
        <h5 style="font-weight:bold;">QnA Website</h5>
        <p>I'm working on my new project QnA website.This web-app will use Django as backend and PostgreSQL for database</p>
        <span class="isDisabled"><a href="#">Currently Ongoing</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want to set the same height of all paragraphs that are present under id='proj_data' div. Whenever I decrease the browser width paragraphs show different height according to text. As you can see my code I'm using bootstrap. How I can do this.

Comment: Id should be unique ! You have used the same id here. Please change it to class

Comment: Do you have any javascript related to this?